# Directly return enum value with associated type

Tags: swift, enums

This is my code:

```
enum Pet {
    case dog(Int), cat(String)
}

protocol PetHolder {
    associatedtype Food

    func determineFood(from: Pet) -> Food?
}

struct DogHolder: PetHolder {
    typealias Food = Int

    func determineFood(from: Pet) -> Int? {
        // Possible one liner? Enum extension?
        switch from {
        case .dog(let food):
            return food
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

In the real code, `Pet` is a generated huge enum. We got lots of classes like DogHolder, which should extract the data based on the associated type of a case in `Pet`.

It isn't maintainable to write for each and every `XHolder` the following (as seen above):

```
// Possible one liner? Enum extension?
switch from {
    case .dog(let food):
        return food
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

This will result in hunderds of lines, in which only `case .dog(let food):` will be different.

I want to see if it holds a specific case and return that one and only associated type of the enum, which is exactly the same as the associated type of the protocol it is implementing. Enum Pet always has one associated value (again, is exactly the same as the protocol the object is implementing).

Edit:

I got this now, but can I remove the else if and inline a possible nil value?

```
if case let Pet.dog(food) = from {
   return food
} else {
    return nil
}
```

Comment: You could do `Mirror(reflecting: pet).children.first?.value as? Int` but I wouldn't really recommend it.

Comment: @dan wow hehe that’s nasty but pretty useful if it works

Comment: This looks like a problem with your software design. So food is a different data type, based on what kind of animal it is?

Comment: @TimTwoToes well yes, that is where the associated type is for. If they all are equal, there is no point in having an associated type.

Comment: @dan if you put your comment in an answer, I will accept that since I use that method now in my project (although it is a little unsafe, I am happy with the code since it safes me hundred lines of code :))